Macvlan Routing an 22.04
I have the following problem. I have an Ubunu 24.04 on which I have docker installed. I created a macvlan on the Docker for the network 192.168.30.0/24.
On the Ubuntu I created an adapter enp1s0.30 with type macvlan and mode bridge on the physical adapter enp1s0 (192.168.10.50).
I also created a default route for 192.168.10.1 to the interface enp1s01. Also a route for 192.168.30.0/24 via 192.168.30.1 dev enp1s0.30.
On the Fritzbox I have entered a fixed route for the network 192.168.30.0/24 nexthop 192.168.10.50.
Now I have the following phenomenon!
I can ping every container in the 192.168.30.0/24 network from the host 192.168.10.50.
I can ping 192.168.10.50 and 192.168.30.1 from all the containers.
I can also ping 192.168.30.1 (enp1s0.30) from any other computer on the network.
But I can't ping any containers from the rest of the network and I can't reach 192.168.10.1 or others from the containers?!
What can I do so that I can reach the containers 192.169.30.0/24 network from the entire 192.168.10.0/24 network?
my ip commands are:
ip link add enp1s0.30 link enp1s0 type macvlan mode bridge
ip addr add 192.168.30.1/32 dev enp1s0.30
ip link set enp1s0.30 up
ip route add 192.168.30.0/24 via 192.168.30.1 dev enp1s0.30
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1 / is set!
I'm despairing here because I know that this works (I've had it running before but I don't remember how) And if anyone else knows how this can be mapped with "netplan".... ;-)
Thank you in advance for your support
